# gRPC client call gives "too many positional arguments" error -- method being called works fine with apart from gRPC

Tags: python, microservices, grpc, grpc-python

I am new to gRPC, I am trying to use it to create a microservice from a python app which I developed.

I of course understand the error message in and of itself; I just cannot see how it is true of the code.  As far as I can tell everything is correct. I have tested the package in isolation and it is working as expected, so I believe the issue is somewhere in what I am doing with gRPC. (Advanced apologies if I am being a complete idiot somehow.)

I have included the code for my server.py, client.py and .proto file below.  The method on the server takes two arguments (self, request) and the client makes the call only passing a `request` variable. However when I run my client script, I receive the following error:

```
❯ python3 my_client.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_client.py", line 16, in <module>
    client.Do_a_thing(request=request)
  File "/home/me/venvs/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 946, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "/home/me/venvs/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 849, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.UNKNOWN
        details = "Exception calling application: Do_a_thing() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given"
        debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1631108483.863151653","description":"Error received from peer ipv6:[::1]:50051","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1069,"grpc_message":"Exception calling application: Do_a_thing() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given","grpc_status":2}"
```

As the method takes one (+ self) argument, and I am passing one argument, I am completely lost as to what is going wrong.

Any and all help, even in the form of advice on how to meaningfully debug a gRPC service, would be massively appreciated.

```py
#server code
import os
import sys
from concurrent import futures
import package # <-- the package I am converting to a microservice

import grpc
from package_pb2 import PackageResponse
import package_pb2_grpc

class PackageService (
    package_pb2_grpc.PackageServicer
):
    def Do_a_thing(self, request):
        return_values = package.function(
            var1=request.var1, 
            var2=request.var2,
            var3=request.var3
        )
        return PackageResponse(response_values=list(return_values))

def serve():
    server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10))
    package_pb2_grpc.add_PackageServicer_to_server(
        PackageService(), server
    )
    server.add_insecure_port("[::]:50051")
    server.start()
    server.wait_for_termination()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    serve()
```

```py
#client code
import grpc
from package_pb2_grpc import PackageStub
from package_pb2 import PackageRequest

channel = grpc.insecure_channel("localhost:50051")
client = PackageStub(channel)

request = PackageRequest(
    var1 = <some_value>,
    var2 = <some_value>,
    var3 = <some_value>
)

client.Do_a_thing(request)
```

```proto
#proto file
syntax = "proto3";

message PackageRequest {
  string var1 = 1;
  string var2 = 2;
  string var3 = 3;
}

message PackageResponse {
  repeated string response_values = 1; //repeated indicates there  may be more than one
}

service Package {
  rpc Do_a_thing(PackageRequest) returns (PackageResponse);
}
```

Comment: The server method implementation should take `context` too. `def Do_a_thing(self, request, context)`

Comment: That was the trick, thank you so much!  I don't suppose you could advice me/point me towards what the context argument is for or is doing?

Comment: Also, it's not just me right-- I feel like that error message does not remotely lend itself to that realisation.  Is there a best practice approach to debugging gRPC services?

Comment: Context is used for e.g. request metadata in gRPC. The server can query the context to determine e.g. Headers associated with the request. The error message is a standard Python error message. It's confusing because it may not be immediately obvious that the server is providing it rather than your client. The clue was the `StatusCode.UNKNOWN` (see: https://grpc.github.io/grpc/core/md_doc_statuscodes.html) and the message `Exception calling application` and that the `_channel` threw it. The gRPC [site](https://grpc.io) is not comprehensive regrettably but it's a good starting point

Comment: Thanks  so much for your help.  You're a star.

Comment: You're welcome! Please consider marking my answer as the answer, thanks!